# Customize entity materialization in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

Is there a way to materialize an instance of your own class that derives from the entity type specified in your model? Let's say I have a "ClassName" property in my model for a given entity and whenever EF materializes an instance of the entity, I want to create an instance of the specified ClassName instead (which is a sub-class of the entity of course).

I know there is the ObjectMaterialized event on the ObjectContext but at this point the entity is already created.

```
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
objectContext.ObjectMaterialized += OnObjectMaterialized;
```

I need a hook right before this to customize the object creation. You might ask why on earth would I need to do this. I have a large object model that changes constantly so I can't define all my classes in the EDMX. The properties that I store in the database can be abstracted to a couple classes at the top of the object model hierarchy. I intend to create entities for those using table-per-type inheritance. But if I could retrieve specific object instances directly when using EF that would be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but the generated entity classes are partial. Can you not simply add your needed functionality to those partial classes?

Comment: To add to @oerkelens' comment, you could also use an extension class. Messing with the generation might come back and bite you when there's a change in class generation

Comment: Adding methods or properties through the partial class won't be enough. I need to create a whole object model with inheritance under the entity classes.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to create custom proxys and debugged deep into the entity framework. I found the **translator** class, which is responsible to create the entities by reflection. The namespace of the class is **System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization**.

The method creating the entites is the private method **Emit_ConstructEntity**. The entity type is a parameter and is created by the private method **LookupObjectMapping** based on an EdmType object (I was using model first).

If you want to change the class, which are created, you have to create a custom MetaDataWorkspace. The workspace is responsible to select the EdmType. Maybe try to debug into the methods yourself and have a look how the MetaDataWorkspace is used to identify the CLR type.